# How to call a function inside a class and with no parameters? Want solutions with no decorator

Tags: python

How to call a function inside a class and with no parameters? I have already knew `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`. What this question is asking are solutions without `@staticmethod`.

This is a question I emerged after learning `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`. I am curious about whether a function like this would become a function that can never be called if it doesn't have any parameters and decorators.

## Detailed Description

```
class RRR:
    def ss():
        print "in ss"
    def x(self):
        ss()
    def y(self):
        self.ss()
    def z(self):
        RRR.ss()
```

I have already knew those methods can't work. But I'm just showing the results to you.

```
>>> a = RRR()
>>> a.x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in x
NameError: global name 'ss' is not defined
>>> a.y()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in y
TypeError: ss() takes no arguments (1 given)
>>> a.z()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in z
TypeError: unbound method ss() must be called with RRR instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I wonder how a function like `RRR.ss()` can be called? Is there any other possible way to call a function like that?

I have already knew, by simply adding a line of `@staticmethod` before `ss()` function, then the function could be called like `self.ss()` or `RRR.ss()`.

But in this question, what I want to ask is, not adding `@staticmethod`, and keeping the declaration code of `RRR.ss` unchanged, is there any way to call `RRR.ss`? Or the function is a function that can never be called?

I am not solving any realistic problem. I'm just curious about the status of this type of function. By such declaration, have I created a useless function, a function that can't be accessed by any ways? This is just a theoretic question.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to make `ss` without arguments callable at all? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: "But in this question, what I want to ask is, keeping the declaration code of RRR.ss unchanged, is there any way to call RRR.ss?" Can't you see this paragraph?

Comment: @JennyaChang: yes, and that question is *unclear*. Why does the OP want that? What is their goal here? Learn about how method objects are created and how they can be unwrapped again? In that case this is a duplicate for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, you hit the point. I am not solving a problem. I'm just curious about the condition of the type of function. By such declaration, have I created a function that can't be accessed by any methods?

Comment: You have created a function that fails to adhere to the conventions expected of methods. That mostly means you don't understand how methods work and *why* they have those conventions. You can still bypass the method creation or unwrap the created method and call the underlying function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters from @Yann Vernier's answer I have known what is `unwrap the created method`. But I still can't figure out what is to `bypass the method`? Can you give a hint?

Comment: Both methods are described in his answer; `a.ss.__func__` or `a.ss.im_func` unwraps, `a.__class__.__dict__['ss']` bypasses the descriptor protocol producing the method object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ss` in your code is not quite a method; it is a callable function placed in a class. When looking up a method, Python binds that method to the instance, injecting a first argument which is guaranteed to be an instance of the correct class (decorators like `classmethod` and `staticmethod` process that argument). This is what happens for `a.x`; it is a class callable looked up via instance attribute, and therefore produces a bound method. Since your `ss` does not accept this argument, it cannot be called with a method call. It can however be called from the class, for instance using `a.__class__.__dict__['ss']()` or `a.ss.im_func()` (which is the unwrapping Martijn Pieters mentioned).

Comment: (1) `a.__class__.ss()` doesn't work (2) how's `a.__class__.ss()` different from `RRR.ss()`? As I know, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

> I have already knew, by simply adding a line of @staticmethod before
>   ss() function, then the function could be called like self.ss() or
>   RRR.ss(). But in this question, what I want to ask is, keeping the
>   declaration code of RRR.ss unchanged, is there any way to call RRR.ss?
>   Or the function is a function that can never be called?

Its not that it can never be called, its just that its not in scope. A class defines a namespace (think of it like a wall with a gate), and everything inside the body of that class is behind the wall. To get to it or to call it, you need to go through the gate, which is either an instance of the class or the class itself.

This is called *resolving*, that is to find out where the name is defined in order to use it. By default, when you run any code it is running in a specific scope; to find out what is available in scope, you can use `globals()` and `locals()` for the global an local scope:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
```

As you see, when you first start up the Python interactive prompt, it has a few things in scope. Now when you create a class, here is what happens:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def a():
...        print 'Hello'
...
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'Foo': <class '__main__.Foo'>, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'Foo': <class '__main__.Foo'>, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
```

You notice only `Foo` is available, not `a`. In order for me to get to `a`, I have to specify its scope by qualifying it with `Foo.` (the `.` is the scope resolution operator).

Comment: Um, this is not a scoping issue (except maybe the attempted call in `RRR.x()`, which I assume the OP only tried out of desperation, because the other ways to invoke the method didn't work).

Comment: `In order for me to get to a, I have to specify its scope by qualifying it with Foo.` But Foo.a() still does't work.

Answer (score 0):

This example should clear things up a bit:

```
class Dog(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        """
        Instance method
        Gets passed the instance as the implicit first argument
        """
        print "My name is '{}'".format(self.name)

    @classmethod
    def get_class(cls):
        """
        Class method
        Gets passed the class as the implicit first argument
        """
        print "I'm the '{}' class".format(cls.__name__)

    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        """
        Static method
        Gets passed *no* implicit arguments. Basically just a
        function attached to a class.
        """
        print "I've got no arguments"


dog = Dog('spot')

dog.get_name()
Dog.get_class()
Dog.foo()
```

Output:

```
My name is 'spot'
I'm the 'Dog' class
I've got no arguments
```

You *can* call static or class methods on the instance (`dog.foo()` or `self.foo()`), but usually you shouldn't, because you're obfuscating the fact that they don't get the instance as an argument.

See the documentation on the [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) and [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorators for more details.

Comment: I have already known `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod`. In this question, what I want to know is, how a method which `doesn't have any decorator functions` and `doesn't have any parameters` can be called.

Comment: It *can't* (easily / without some black magic). It will be a regular instance method, which will need to be bound to an instance (implicit instance argument) or explicitely passed an instance as the first argument - which will violoate it's signature if it doesn't take any arguments.